# Not all points are showing on layers from Google Maps Engine in map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-engine

I'm using the Google Maps API Visualization library to display layers that I have created in Google Maps Engine.  Each layer has approximately 1900 points on it.  When viewing in Maps Engine, I can see all 1900 points in the 20 layers I have made.  All 1900 points are the same in each of the layers.  When I load these 20 layers into a map with the Maps API and display them sequentially, not all the points are displayed in all the layers. So I get a flashing effect as the map switches between layers and points disappear and reappear.  Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: How are you displaying the points using the Maps API?  Are you using a MapsEngineLayer or are you querying for the points & drawing them yourself?  Could you provide some code too?